# Are bipolar function and sign function same?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

we know about bipolar activation function in neural networks as:

> $f(n) = \begin{cases}
> 1,  & \text{if $n$ > = 0} \\
> -1, & \text{if $n$ < 0}
> \end{cases}$

and we know about sign activation function as:

> $f(n) = \begin{cases}
> 1,  & \text{if $n$ > 0} \\
> 0,  & \text{if $n$ = 0} \\
> -1, & \text{if $n$ < 0}
> \end{cases}$

can we say bipolar is a special case of sign ?

Comment: They are the same unless $n=0$ in which case they are different.  Whether $n=0$ has a probability $>0$ or not may affect whether they are materially different

Comment: @Henry That could well be an answer, not just a comment.